# Update Emacs to the latest version on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, emacs

I installed Linux Mint 20 on a new machine, and I have the default Emacs version:

```
➜  ~ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep emacs
emacs                       install
emacs-bin-common                install
emacs-common                    install
emacs-el                    install
emacs-gtk                   install
emacsen-common                  install
```

How I can clean my dev environment and install the latest version of emacs? It should be 27.1.

Comment: Before doing this, make sure it is worth the trouble of bringing in software from outside your main repositories. Emacs has been pretty stable for a long time, unless you need a _specific_ feature available only in 27.1 (I use 27.1, by the way, and haven't noticed anything special) just stick with the one in the repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest emacs version in Ubutnu repositories is `26` , you need to add a third party repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs
sudo apt update
```

Check it:

```
$ apt policy  emacs27

emacs27:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 27.1~1.git86d8d76aa3-kk2+20.04
  Version table:
     27.1~1.git86d8d76aa3-kk2+20.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

You can install `emacs27` alongside the previous version, but if you need to remove all the installed versions, you can run:

```
sudo apt remove emacs
```

Install it:

```
sudo apt install emacs27
```

Comment: I need to remove my previous package? I can have problem with it?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I have update my answer. use `sudo apt remove emacs.` do not forget the dot at the end.

Comment: `Unable to locate package emacs.`

Comment: Will `sudo apt remove emacs.` work? I don't use apt-based systems any more, but shouldn't that be `sudo apt remove emacs*` or, if it needs regex `sudo apt remove emacs.*`?